# Get filename with regex

Tags: java, string

I have many .json file in a folder. And I have to get a file with full name "ranjans-vra2-standalone-269d9199a-0.vraCafe.0-nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json". Like wise I have so many folders and I want to get only this file out of those folders. For that I want to use regex.

The common thing for each file is: "vraCafe" and ".json".

I have to use it as testbedPath abd supply to JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = readSimpleJson(testbedPath);
```

What regex sholud I use to get testbedPath?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex you can use:

```
([\w\S]*(vraCafe)[\w\S]*(\.json)$)
```

It will match each file name with the fileextension `.json` and 
`vraCafe` in the name.

For Example:

```
ranjansvra-vra2-standalone-ve269d9199a-0.0-nimbus-vra-vraCafedeploy-result.json
```

or

```
ranjansvra-vra2-svraCafetandalone-ve269d9199a-0.0-nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json
```

[See the running example](http://ideone.com/3Zp1FF):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String filename = "ranjansvra-vra2-svraCafetandalone-ve269d9199a-0.0-nimbus-vra-deploy-result.json";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([\\w\\S]*(vraCafe)[\\w\\S]*(\\.json)$)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matches");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find if the filename contains 'vraCafe' and '.json', if yes, delete it.

```
 if(fileName.contains("vraCafe") && fileName.contains(".json")){
    //get it and delete it
  }
```

Edit:
In order to have a concrete check on file extension

```
 if(fileName.contains("vraCafe") && fileName.endsWith(".json")){
    //get it and delete it
  }
```

Comment: I'd use `&& fileName.endsWith(".json")` to be sure the `.json` is the file extension.

Comment: that is a good point, just on the safe side ... Agreed..adding it

Comment: The problem here is I am getting testbedPath from testNG file as a parameter to java. I wanted to use some regex to get it directly.